# Take limit in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have this equation :

```
eqkk = 
  D[k[t], {t,2}] - ((3 sola'[t]/sola[t]) + (3 sola''[t]/sola'[t]) - 
    (1/(sola'[t] sola[t]^2))) D[k[t], t]
```

To get $k(t)$:

```
solk = NDSolveValue[{eqkk == 0, k[0] == 1, k'[0] ==0}, k, {t, tmin,tmax}]`
```

Now I want to evaluate `solk`, not at `k'[0] == 0`, but to take the limit of `solk` as `k'[0] -> 0`

#### Edit

`sola[t]` is another function solved before with `NDSolveValue` as well. Consider for instance `sola[t]` is like `y[t]`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's `sola[t]`?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: It might be easier for people to help you if you provide the code that defines `sola[t]`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to solve the system of ode's in `{k[t],sola[t]}` in one step?

Comment: @Dr.phy Use `solk = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqkk == 0, k[0] == 1, k'[0] == p}, 
  k, {t, tmin, tmax}, {p}]`, then the function `solk[p][t]` has a limit `solk[0][t]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, thanks , I will try this.